# gcc: __fread_chk_warn warning

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, fread

I have a compilation problem with gcc.

Assume the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(const char *fname) {
    FILE *fh = fopen(fname, "rb");
    int tmp;
    if (fread(&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, fh) < 1) {
        tmp = 0;
    }
    fclose(fh);
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", test("test.txt"));
    return 0;
}
```

And the file `test.txt`:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111...
```

Of course, the program is very stupid, but it works:

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp/optxx$ gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra test.c
user@ubuntu:~/tmp/optxx$ ./a.out
825307441
```

Let's modify it a bit (only add an attribute to the `test`-function):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) test(const char *fname) {
    FILE *fh = fopen(fname, "rb");
    int tmp;
    if (fread(&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, fh) < 1) {
        tmp = 0;
    }
    fclose(fh);
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", test("test.txt"));
    return 0;
}
```

The function `test` should no longer be optimized. But now compilation fails:

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp/optxx$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 test.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:936:0,
                 from test.c:1:
In function ‘fread’,
    inlined from ‘test’ at test.c:6:9:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:293:9: warning: call to ‘__fread_chk_warn’ declared with attribute warning: fread called with bigger size * nmemb than length of destination buffer
  return __fread_chk_warn (__ptr, __bos0 (__ptr), __size, __n, __stream);
         ^
```

I get a warning and normally i compile with `-Werror`, so i don't like warnings.
The used `gcc` version:

```
user@ubuntu:~/tmp/optxx$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.3.1-6ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.1 20160119 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-6ubuntu2)
```

Unfortunately i am not able to fix the warning:(

Maybe someone has an idea why this happens?

-edit-

A (dirty) hack would also be okay to remove this warning:)

-edit-

Probably something with my linux is wrong, because it seems to work for everyone else. Anayway a dirty hack / fix would be to add this code before the `fread` call:

```
static size_t fread_wrapper(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream) {
    return fread(ptr, size, count, stream);
}
#define fread(ptr, size, count, stream)         fread_wrapper((ptr), (size), (count), (stream))
```

Comment: No error for me with gcc 4.4.5.

Comment: Unfortunately i also get an error with `gcc 4.6.4`. I hope it's not a bug of gcc.

Comment: Works fine for me with gcc 5.3.0 !

Comment: I tried on a RHEL 5 box (Linux hostname 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) with GCC versions 4.1.2, 4.5.1, 4.7.1, 5.2.0, 5.3.0 with the options: `/path/to/version/bin/gcc -std=c99 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition  so-34907503-b.c -o so-34907503-b' and after adding `static` before `test` (to avoid `-Wmissing-prototypes`), it compiled without problem.

Comment: tested on gcc 4.6.3, no problem reproduced

Comment: I don't think gcc version matters much. Try compiling with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` and you should trigger it. This flag is enabled by default in Ubuntu and not most other Linuxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu enable the `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` feature by default for optimization levels `-O1` or higher. This option makes the system headers pre-process to use different functions for `fread` among others. Those functions perform some basic safety checks of arguments. The option gets enabled globally when the header is included so it makes the assumption that all the code will be compiled with `-O1` or higher. I assume that it is disabled on lower optimization levels because gcc doesn't have enough information without some optimizations and that causes those magic fortify macros to generate false positives (like you got).

If you compile the whole file with `-O0`, `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is disabled and things will work. Alternatively I guess you can compile the whole file with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`, although I haven't tried it.

Also, I could reproduce this on other flavors of linux by just adding `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`.

I guess you can call it a compiler/glibc/Ubuntu bug. Or just stop using crazy optimization attributes. The world can't be tested with all possible weird combinations so we should exercise caution when pushing buttons and turning knobs.

Comment: This works great. Thanks:) I know that i sometimes try some special combinations of such "hacks", but for real world applications i avoid such things. Anyway: Thanks!:)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't realized it's Ubuntu that is breaking my CI build with its helpful compile flags. BTW, Clear Linux is even more notorious with injecting its own "optimized" flags into the environment.